# C# equivalent of Python's id()?

Tags: c#, python, mutability

Is there a C# equivalent to Python's [id()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id)? If not, how can I test if an object has changed? For example, in Python, an immutable object:

```
>>> s = "abc"
>>> id(s)
11172320
>>> s += "d"
>>> id(s)
18632928
```

and a mutable one:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(a)
11259656
>>> a += [4]
>>> id(a)
11259656
```

Edit - Most of the answers so far are about *comparison functions/operators* but I'm more interested in the values that are being compared. I wasn't initially clear about that, and I'm accepting `Object.ReferenceEquals` as the answer.

Comment: @wes: I think you have immutable and mutable reversed in your examples.

Comment: @calavera: Why? Mutable objects can be modified in-place, immutable objects require a new object to represent the modifications.

Comment: @wes: I don't know a lot of python.  I was thinking of the id() function as a hash function rather than an object reference/id/key.  So if example (a) was immutable, the hash value would not change, and vice versa.  So obviously I was thinking about it in the wrong context :)

Comment: @wes: your edit makes it more clear.  That's exactly what confused me, I thought you were concerned with whether the same in-memory object's value had changed rather than whether a new object had been created.

Comment: I'm curious as to your use case for Python's id(). Why do you need it?

Comment: @Russell: Just to quickly check mutability of types as I'm learning C#. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can use the [`Object.ReferenceEquals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) function:

> Determines whether the specified Object instances are the same instance.

To borrow your Python example a little bit:

```
List<int> listA = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> listB = listA;
listA.Add(4);

bool equal = object.ReferenceEquals(listA, listB);
```

`equal` will be `true`.

Answer (score 5):

You can test object identity with [`Object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

I think you're asking the wrong question. My answer is quite detailed, but here's a quick summary:

- There is no direct equivalent to `id` in C#.
- You can get get the address of an object in C# using pointers, but you **shouldn't use this** to solve your problem.
- The method [`object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) does something similar to what you are trying to do.
- The problem you are trying to solve doesn't really exist in C# in the same way is it does in Python.
- The way you are using `id` doesn't solve the problem in Python either.

---

Firstly, I'll post from the [documentation for id](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id) since most people don't seem to have read it. Please **do** read this because the rest of my answer only makes sense if you know what `id` does (and no, it doesn't create a hash code):

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object.

C# doesn't have an equivalent to `id` but it is possible to get the address of the object by getting a pointer to the object in unsafe mode.

```
unsafe
{
     IntPtr x = (IntPtr)(&v);
     Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

However you **shouldn't do this** in C#. You very rarely need to use unsafe code in C#, and if you do it can easily spread as code that calls your code also becomes unsafe. There are other ways to solve your problem that don't need unsafe code. Besides, in .NET (unlike in Python) objects can be moved about in memory by the garbage collector, so if you want a single identity that remains constant for the entire lifetime of the object, the memory address is of no use to you. You should instead create a readonly property, called `Id` for example.

---

An alternative approach which is possible in C# without using unsafe code is to test if two variables have the same reference using [`Object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx). However you probably shouldn't do this either. C# doesn't have the same ambiguity as in Python. To set a variable to point to a new object you use the `=` operator. Calling a method almost always won't change the reference, so you shouldn't worry about it. In C# `x += y;` operator is (very nearly) equivalent to `x = x + y` and you can't change that like you can in Python.

---

Also, as mentioned in the documentation, your Python example is flawed - `id` cannot be used reliably to test if an object has changed. Example:

```
>>> s='abc'
>>> id(s)
37822208
>>> s+='d'
>>> id(s)
61711680    # Changes
>>> s+='e'
>>> id(s)
61711680    # Oops... doesn't change even though the value changed.
```

In Python if you have to compare two objects to see if they are the same object (and you probably shouldn't be doing this) then use `is` which is the Python equivalent of `object.ReferenceEquals`. `id` is only guaranteed to be the constant over the lifetime of an object. As shown above `id` is **not** guaranteed to be different for different objects. In particular if one of the objects no longer exists you can (and sometimes will) get the same `id` due to reuse of the same memory. As such the use of `id` is a really bad idea here.

**Summary**

Don't do it.

Comment: Thanks for putting so much effort into this reply.

Answer (score 3):

`object.GetHashcode()` might be worth a shot.

Comment: By design, this is usually overridden such that it will return the same value on equal values, which misses the point.  Forcing a call to a base method that has been overridden cannot be done cleanly.  You can get base hashcode of the object pretty easily by just calling `InternalGetHashCode` instead via reflection: `MethodInfo dynMethod = (typeof(object)).GetMethod("InternalGetHashCode", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);int myHashCode = (int)dynMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { myObject });` .  That said, different objects might have the same hash code, so it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

wes, the correct answer to your question, ie.. an analogous function to id() is

> object.GetHashCode()